# React Context "Property 'state' does not exist" when using useContext() on Context consumer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to implement Contexts in my React project. Every time I have tried implementing this Context, I get the same error:

```
Property 'state' does not exist on type '{ count: number; currentColor: string; }'.

  > 40 |   let { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(ContextOne);
       |         ^
```

Context Provider code:

```
import * as React from "react";

let ContextOne = React.createContext(initialState);

let initialState = {
  count: 10,
  currentColor: "#bada55"
};

let reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "reset":
      return initialState;
    case "increment":
      return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
    case "decrement":
      return { ...state, count: state.count - 1 };
    case "set-color":
      return { ...state, currentColor: action.payload };
  }
};

function ContextOneProvider(props) {
  let [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  let value = { state, dispatch };


  return (
    <ContextOne.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</ContextOne.Provider>
  );
}

let ContextOneConsumer = ContextOne.Consumer;

export { ContextOne, ContextOneProvider, ContextOneConsumer };
```

I have tried numerous online example Context Providers, but every time useContext() is called, the same error appears. What needs to be modified to get the Context working?

------------------------------------------Edit------------------------------------------

Thanks to soywood, here is the working Context Provider code:

```
import * as React from "react";

type State = {
  count: number
  currentColor: string
}

const initialState: State = {
  count: 10,
  currentColor: "#bada55",
};

type Context = {
  state: State
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<Action>
}

type Action = {
  type: string,
  payload: string
}
const ContextOne = React.createContext<Context>({
  state: initialState,
  dispatch: () => {},
});

// You need to define the type Action
const reducer: React.Reducer<State, Action> = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "reset":
      return initialState;
    case "increment":
      return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
    case "decrement":
      return { ...state, count: state.count - 1 };
    case "set-color":
      return { ...state, currentColor: action.payload };
  }
};

function ContextOneProvider(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const value: Context = { state, dispatch };

  return (
    <ContextOne.Provider value={value}>{props.children} </ContextOne.Provider>
  );
}

let ContextOneConsumer = ContextOne.Consumer;

export { ContextOne, ContextOneProvider, ContextOneConsumer };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `createContext` parameter type should match your `ContextOne.Provider` value type. You also need to improve your types to guide more the `TypeScript` compiler:

```js
import * as React from "react";

type State = {
  count: number
  currentColor: string
}

const initialState: State = {
  count: 10,
  currentColor: "#bada55",
};

type Context = {
  state: State
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<State>
}

const ContextOne = React.createContext<Context>({
  state: initialState,
  dispatch: () => {},
});

// You need to define the type Action
const reducer: React.Reducer<State, Action> = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "reset":
      return initialState;
    case "increment":
      return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
    case "decrement":
      return { ...state, count: state.count - 1 };
    case "set-color":
      return { ...state, currentColor: action.payload };
  }
};

function ContextOneProvider(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const value: Context = { state, dispatch };

  return (
    <ContextOne.Provider value={value}>{props.children} </ContextOne.Provider>
  );
}

let ContextOneConsumer = ContextOne.Consumer;

export { ContextOne, ContextOneProvider, ContextOneConsumer };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After making that change, I'm getting a different error. "Property 'disptach' is missing in type '{ state: any; dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>; }' but required in type '{ state: { count: number; currentColor: string; }; disptach: () => void; }'." Which I am getting when setting the Provider value "<ContextOne.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</ContextOne.Provider>".

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo `disptach` instead of `dispatch`... I update my answer.

Comment: No worries, thank you for all the help. The error that appears now is "Type '{ state: any; dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>; }' is not assignable to type '{ state: { count: number; currentColor: string; }; dispatch: () => void; }'. Types of property 'dispatch' are incompatible.  Type 'Dispatch<any>' is not assignable to type '() => void'.". I tried changing the initialState declaration to "dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>", but it tells me "'(' expected.".

Comment: Do you use plain JavaScript or TypeScript ?

Comment: I'm using TypeScript.

Comment: So you need to type properly your variables and functions to guide the TypeScript compiler. I updated my answer.

Comment: The Consumer is correctly pulling the initial value of 10 for count. When I call dispatch({type: "increment",  payload: ""}) from the consumer, the state doesn't change. I'd expect the count to now be 11, but it stays at 10. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: let { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(ContextOne); To print count: <h2>{state.count}</h2>. Button to increment: <button onClick={inc}>Increment!</button>. Inc function: function inc (){  console.log('inc');  dispatch({ type: "increment", payload: ""}); }. The function is being called, as it logs to the console, but the count never changes.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Could you provide a snippet so I can help you more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're providing an initial state to your context provider which has the properties `count` and `currentColor`, while the value (the new state) you provide in `ContextOneProvider` has the properties `state` and `dispatch`.

I imagine you'll want to swap initialState to be something along the lines of:

```
{
  state: null,
  dispatch: null,
}
```

If you're using typescript you may want to provide an interface that has those as optional params.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After making those changes, I get an error that says "Type '{ state: any; dispatch: Dispatch<any>; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ count: number; currentColor: string; }': count, currentColor", which I am getting when setting the Provider value at "Which I am getting when setting the Provider value "<ContextOne.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</ContextOne.Provider>"